# Moving Views folder MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am quite new to MVC and I was just wondering if it is possible to move the `Views` folder? Basically, I am trying to make it so that my folder structure lies like this:

Content -> Themes -> (Brand) -> Views

For every brand, it will have its own `Images` folder and `css` file as well as its own Views folder. How would I go about setting this structure up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Razor view engine in the [ViewEngines.Engines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewengines.engines.aspx) collection and change [ViewLocationFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine.viewlocationformats%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: The -1 baffles me as well, clear/concise answer that takes care of the problem...?  +1